# How to preserve BottomNavigationView on Activity transition?

Tags: android, android-activity, bottomnavigationview

I have an app that uses BottomNavigationView with Fragments, but I need to change them to Activities because of new specifications. How can I keep the BottomNavigationView visible all the time between the transitions of Activities? One easy example is the Spotify Android app.

Comment: I am assuming Spotify is using fragments. You would have to have all the activity layouts have a bottom navigation. I would try my best to make the specifications fit the fragments.

Comment: You can try this https://github.com/ddekanski/BottomNavigationViewBetweenActivities

Comment: I actually followed this guide to make it work. Although, it animates the BottomNavigationView with the whole activity.